# Compact customisable class?

Tags: pdftex, document-classes, article, amsart

Is there a document class like amsart in that it has compact list's and headings? It just needs to not be an ams class, because they have specific guidelines, and so are not very customisable. I've added an example of what I mean by compact lists. I don't want to use something like savetrees, because the ams classes still look good despite taking less space and being more compact.

amsart
[image: Compact lists.]

vs

article

[image: Non-compact list]

Here is the code for the list (Although this is not just for lists. The ams classes make everything more compact.):

```tex
\begin{enumerate}
\item ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit)
    \subitem Arithmetic Operations
    \subitem Logical Operations
\item CU (Control Unit)
    \subitem Directs electrical signals
    \subitem Doesn't execute program
\item AGU (Address Generation Unit)
\item MMU (Memory Management Unit)
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: As long as you're not planning to submit the result to AMS for publication, you can ignore the instructions about not using packages like `geometry`.  While a few packages aren't compatible, many are, so it may still be worth a try.

Comment: Can you please add the code you're using for the list?

Comment: Sure, but it's not just for lists. It's for something generally more compact, like ams classes are.

Comment: Perhaps if you can be specific about what you would want to change in the AMS classes (other than the "obvious" request not to use `geometry`, which I've already addressed), some more practical advice could be provided.

Comment: I'd like to change things like the toc style (would also like to use some package like multitoc), and want section and subsection numbers in the margins. I'm going to be writing about 20 pages of notes, and want them to be compact to be able to find things in them quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memoir` class has macros `\firmlist` and `\tightlist` which can be used at the beginning of a list (`itemize`, `enumerate`, `description`) environment. `\tightlist` removes all vertical spaces between list entries while `\firmlist` reduces the spaces.

Comment: I know there are specific ways to do lists, but I was just wanting something more compact overall, and by default. For everything, not just lists. It would be too much to tweak everything manually.

Comment: @OctopuSS7 Your original question was only about lists but now you have broadened it. In any case I suggest you look seriously at the `memoir` class which provides many means of controlling the typeset result. For example `\setsecindent{1cm}` will move the section number 1cm into the margin. It is up to you to specify the output you want --- nobody here is a mind reader. --- GOM

Answer (score 0):

For lists, I've found this works well with the article class:

```latex
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label={(\arabic*) -}}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\setenumerate{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
```